# How do you escape namespace string

Tags: php, namespaces

New to namespace in php and trying to call a dummy class. Here is the code below

```
include "App/Controllers/Home.php";
// This code works but I commented it out to try it the otherway
//$home = new \App\Controllers\Home();

$namespace = "\App\Controllers\\";
$home = new  $namespace . Home();
$home->index();
```

It shows error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class '\App\Controllers\' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\namespace\index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\namespace\index.php on line 16

I believe I am not escaping the namespace right, can you help?

Comment: and where do you require that class? Also, why are you declaring $namespace as a var to use on the next line?

Comment: I need to load the class via a loader, I need to add the namespace as variable or constant to the loader later ... so experimenting with it.

Comment: Why not just declare the namespace `namespace \App\Controllers;` then `$home = new Home;`? Or you can do the entire thing in one go (using single quotes means you don't have to escape the backslash), `$class = '\App\Controllers\Home\'; $home = new $class();`

Comment: Not really about escaping … notice how the error message says, _“Class '\App\Controllers\' not found”_ - no mention of `Home` at all? That’s because of [Operator Precedence](https://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) - `new` has the highest there is, so what you have written is basically equivalent to `(new  $namespace) . (Home())`, and that is of course not what you want.

Comment: I updated the whole thing, will be glad if you could see again.

Comment: Are you using a framework of some kind?

Comment: no, no framework .... its kinda in house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As misorude suggest you can try :

```
$namespace = "\\App\Controllers\\";
$classname = $namespace . 'Home';
$home = new  $classname();
$home->index();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer using single-quote for namespaces - using double quote may result some surprising effects since some sequences have [special meaning](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) if they're enclosed in double-quotes. With single-quotes you need to care only about trailing `\` since `\'` will work as escaped `'` and it will not be interpreted as end of the string:

```
$namespace = 'App\Controllers\\';
```

But this is unusual situation, usually you're using FQN, so there is no such problem:

```
$className = 'App\Controllers\Home';
$home = new $className();
```

Or just use `::class` - this is more IDE and SCA firendly:

```
$className = \App\Controllers\Home::class;
$home = new $className();
```